# HTML: Centering the container

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm working on [THIS](http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/) site. For some reason, the class 'title' and 'container' aren't on the center of the page even though I used 'margin: 0px auto;' property. I'm almost 100% sure it's something within CSS but I can't figure what.

CSS

```
.container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 545px;
    height: auto;
}

.title {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.elemento1 {
    float: left;
    width: 266;
    height: auto;
}

.elemento2 {
    float: right;
    width: 266;
    height: auto;
}

.foot {
    clear: both;
}
```

The front page

```
<div class="title">
<font size="20">WE LIKE TO PLAY FOOTBALL</font>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="elemento1">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="anim">
<p><a title="Edizione 2013" href="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/edizione-2013/"><img alt="" src="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/dividere-quadrato.jpg"/></a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="foot">
</div>

<div class="elemento1">

<div class="wrap">
<div class="anim">
<a title="Edizione 2013" href="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/edizione-2013/"><img alt="" src="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/dividere-quadrato.jpg"/></a>
</div>
</div>

<p>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="anim">
<a title="Edizione 2013" href="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/edizione-2013/"><img alt="" src="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/dividere-quadrato.jpg"/></a>
</div>
</div>
</p>

<div class="wrap">
<div class="anim">
<a title="Edizione 2013" href="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/edizione-2013/"><img alt="" src="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/dividere-quadrato.jpg"/></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="elemento2">


<div class="wrap">
<div class="anim2">
<a title="Edizione 2013" href="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/edizione-2013/"><img alt="" src="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/dividere-quadrato.jpg"/></a>
</div>
</div>

<p>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="anim2">
<a title="Edizione 2013" href="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/edizione-2013/"><img alt="" src="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/dividere-quadrato.jpg"/></a>
</div>
</div>
</p>

<div class="wrap">
<div class="anim2">
<a title="Edizione 2013" href="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/edizione-2013/"><img alt="" src="http://wordpressitis.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/dividere-quadrato.jpg"/></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="foot">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include relevant html markup (so we can reproduce the issue), and perhaps also trim the css down to only the *relevant* bits? Makes it a lot convenient and pleasant for us to help you.

Comment: You can always tell which sites were written by using a tool, and which were written by hand. I would say that roughly 40% of that markup and CSS is pure bloat.

Comment: Apparently not because I wrote everything by myself, except for the class that makes the images move [SOURCE](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp). I usually use Notepad++. This particular code was written within wordpress "editor" (it doesn't provide any formatting options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.wrap{margin:0 auto;}`. And take down the width from this class. For me it works.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width:266px;` and `height:267px;` from `.wrap`.

**YOUR CSS**

```
.wrap {
    width: 266px;
    height: 267px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see there is a small problem with your entire code. The first problem is because your title is under "div class="wrap clearfix" id="inner-content" and its width is just 266px. So if you manage to get your title out of it then I think that you should be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of your wrap class, just remove it :)

/Edit: Or at least remove it from the div "inner-content"

Comment: I need it, otherwise when the square move it leaves unused spaced that other squares go to replace.

Comment: And why do you marked an answer where width and hight gets removed as correct? Nevermind :)

Comment: Yes but the class must remain in its position otherwise other squares will move. Apparently it's sufficient just "wrapping" the image without specifying the dimension and it will adapt. However I left the 'height' attribute just to be sure :)

Answer (score 0):

---

```
.wrap {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 545px;
height: 267px;
}
should fix it
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your using IE as its better in Google Chrome and Firefox but footer in wrong place.  Your using  not foot as in css listed.  Just change your .foot in css to footer (assuming your using html5)

footer{
clear: both
}

You might want to look into browser specific code (search here or google it).  Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try to Put the title div in a container with fixed width at 100%